# integrating a web server into a python script

Tags: python, web-scraping, bioinformatics

I have written a program to generate sequences that pass certain filters (the exact sequences etc don't matter).  Each sequence is generated by making a random string of 40 characters made up of C, G, T or A. When each string is generated, it is put through a set of filters, and if it passes the filters it is saved to a list.

I am trying to make one of those filters include an online tool, BPROM, which doesn't appear to have a python library implementation.  This means I will need to get my python script to send the sequence string described above to the online tool, and save the output as a python variable.

My question is, if I have a url to the tool (http://www.softberry.com/berry.phtml?topic=bprom&group=programs&subgroup=gfindb), how can I interface my script that generates the sequences, with the online tool - is there a way to send data to the web tool and save the tool's output as a variable?  I've been looking into requests but i'm not sure it is the right way to approach this (as a massive python/coding noob).

Thanks for reading, I'm a bit brain dead so I hope this made sense :P

Comment: Try making POST request to the perl cgi script path where that form (in the link) is sending data to.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can use `requests` or `urllib`
Here is demo code:

```py
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.softberry.com/berry.phtml?topic=bprom&group=programs&subgroup=gfindb') as response:
   html = response.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  From what I understand, the output of your code is the html code of the web page (that's what I see when I print it at least).  This is definitely a thick question, but how do I get the output value of the tool from this HTML code?  Should I put the sequence in the url open method as the 'Data' parameter?  If the output of your code is a HTTPResponse Object (https://docs.python.org/2.2/lib/httpresponse-objects.html) then should I be looking for the header that corresponds to the results in the page properties and using the get header function?

Comment: you can try regex for simple solution, or Beautiful Soup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
if that helped you please mark this answer as the right one, thanks